# The sum of Brownian motion increments

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

As I am studying about Brownian motion, as a preparation for my exam, I came across the following problem that I would like some help for:
Let $\{B(t), t ≥ 0\}$ be a standard Brownian motion and set $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} |B(\frac{i}{2^n}) - B(\frac{i-1}{2^n}) |$. Show that $E[Y_n] = 2^{n/2}\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $\sum^∞_{k=1} P(Y_k < k) < \infty$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the distribution of the increments $B(i/2^n)-B((i-1)/2^n)$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen We know that the increments are normally distributed with mean 0 and variance = $i/2^n -(i-1)/2^n = 1/2^n$. So we have the sum of $N(0, 1/2^n)$ variables. Is there a way we could use the Strong Law of Large Numbers to find the expectation?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Rather, we have the sum of $|N(0, 1/2^n)|$, which is actually the folded normal distribution. We can use its formula to find the mean, right?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Comment: @UBM Yes it did for the first part, thank you. But I am not sure about proving the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_1, Z_2, \dots$ be the sequence of i.i.d. standard normal variables. Then

$$ Y_n
\stackrel{d}= \frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \left| Z_k \right|. $$

So by the Chebyshev's inequality,

$$ \mathbb{P}(\left| Y_n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n]\right| > \lambda) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)}{\lambda^2} = \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\left|Z_1\right|)}{\lambda^2}. $$

Using this, we estimate that

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_n < n)
= \mathbb{P}(Y_n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n] < n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n])
\leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\left|Z_1\right|)}{(\mathbb{E}[Y_n] - n)^2}
\sim \frac{C}{2^n} $$

as $n\to\infty$, where $C = \frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{Var}(\left|Z_1\right|)$ is an absolute constant. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y_n < n)$ converges by the limit comparison test.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Isn't $Var(Y_n) = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}Var(|Z_1|) = $, rather than just $Var(|Z_1|)$? Also, in the last part I believe we need to use $1 - P(Y_n)$ so that we can apply Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: @EM823823, Using the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ for independent $X$ and $Y$, we have $$\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)=\frac{1}{(2^{n/2})^2}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\operatorname{Var}(\left|Z_k\right|)=\operatorname{Var}(\left|Z_1\right|).$$ Also, since $n-\mathbb{E}[Y_n]<0$ for large $n$, we have $$Y_n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n] < n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n]\qquad\implies \left|Y_n - \mathbb{E}[Y_n]\right| > \mathbb{E}[Y_n]-n.$$ This is why we can utilize the Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my questions!